# Move to specified coords - libgdx and java

Tags: java, libgdx, vector

So I am making my bullets go to a point and travel further. Only its acting really really weird. Its like its thinking that the 0,0 location is at the top left instead of the bottom left.

This is the code:

```
float speed = 100;

    Vector2 direction;
    Vector2 thisPos = new Vector2(getX(), getY());
    Vector2 mousePos;

    public Bullet(){
        super();
        setSprite(sprite);
        setX(0); setY(0);
        float dx = Gdx.input.getX() - getX();
        float dy = Gdx.input.getY() - getY();
        mousePos = new Vector2(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY());
        direction = new Vector2(dx, dy);
        //sprite.setRotation(direction.angle(thisPos));
        direction.nor();
    }

    public void update(){
        Vector2 dirAd = new Vector2(direction);
        thisPos.x += dirAd.x * speed * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        thisPos.y += dirAd.y * speed * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
        setPosition(thisPos.x, thisPos.y);
        super.update();
    }
```

I hope someone can help me what I did wrong with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply because in the screen coordinate system `(0, 0)` *is* the top left corner. This is also called the `y-down` coordinate system.
[image: Screen coordinate system]

If you wish to use the standard (y-up) coordinate system you can calculate the corresponding point on the screen by calculating `screenHeight - yPosition`. So on your case you could make your `setY()` method look something like this:

```
public void setY(int y) {
    int newY = Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - y;
    thisPos.y = newY; // Or however you set your position...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to make (0,0) the bottom left an easy way to do this would be to:

setPosition(getGlobalBounds().width, getGlobalBounds().height)